# Determing why the Integral comparison test cannot be used

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Hey guys I have this homework problem that I am having difficulty explaining. The question is why the integral comparison test cannot be used. The Series is:

```
The sum of the indefinite series from n=1 to infinity is equal to cos^2(n)/(1+n^2).
```

I see that the series is positive and is continuously decreasing, but I can't seem to find the integral of the series and explain why you can't use the integral comparison test.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is not decreasing because values of $\cos^2n$ fluctuate between $0$ and $1$. So, the best you can say about is that $0<\cos^2n/(1+n^2)<1$.